# Eclipse (Java) - Excecute a class (via Command)

Tags: java, eclipse, command

I am fairly new to programming and got a probably "stupid" question.

I have a programm: 3 Classes.

---

First one(main): - create Frame
           - make a panel (panel1)

Second one: - set a picture as background for panel1

Third: - remove picture from panel1

---

When I change from the main class to the third class (per actionListener, actionPerformed stuff), the image gets deleted. Now how do I tell my programm to execute the second class (recreate the image).

To be honest I don't even know how the programm knows it should excecute the 2nd class at first (friend helped me, but is on holiday atm).

Thanks for a short answer!

Sincerly
Moritz

Comment: That is way too much code. Perhaps you can reduce it to an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't reduce it, because as stated in the question I don't even know what I am looking for. (code now deleted)